# (open + write) vs. (fopen + fwrite) to kernel /proc/

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, fwrite

I have a very strange bug. If I do:

```
    int fd = open("/proc/...", O_WRONLY);
    write(fd, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
    close(fd);
```

everything is working including for a very long string which length > 1024.

If I do:

```
    FILE *fd = fopen("/proc/...", "wb");
    fwrite(argv[1], 1, strlen(argv[1]), fd);
    fclose(fd);
```

the string is cut around 1024 characters.

I'm running an ARM embedded device with a 3.4 kernel. I have debugged in the kernel and I see that the string is already cut when I reach the very early function vfs_write (I spotted this function with a WARN_ON instruction to get the stack).

The problem is the same with fputs vs. puts.

I can use fwrite for a very long string (>1024) if I write to a standard rootfs file. So the problem is really linked how the kernel handles /proc.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: fwrite buffers the data so you will need to perform a flush call and the remaining data should be stored in the file.

Comment: @ClaudioCorsi: `fclose()`  automatically flushes the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the problem is with buffers.

The issue is that special files, such as those at `/proc` are, well..., special, they are not always simple stream of bytes, and have to be written to (or read from) with specific sizes and or offsets. You do not say what file you are writing to, so it is impossible to be sure.

Then, the call to `fwrite()` assumes that the output fd is a simple stream of bytes, so it does smart fancy things, such as buffering and splicing and copying the given data. In a regular file it will just work, but in a special file, funny things may happen.

Just to be sure, try to run `strace` with both versions of your program and compare the outputs. If you wish, post them for additional comments.

Comment: It's a custom driver but nothing fancy. The entry is created with the usual create_proc_entry.

Comment: @gregoiregentil: Ah, you wrote the driver? Then maybe you are handling the writes wrong. Probably your single `fwrite()` call is converted from inside glibc into serveral sucessive calls to `write()`. As I said, you can check it with `strace`.

Comment: Here are the two straces: http://pastebin.com/3kRL8nmn Very strange how the fwrite do mmap2 and then only writes indeed 1024 characters

Comment: @gregoiregentil: The `mmap2` is a anonymous map for allocating the file buffer (big mallocs are usually mmapped). Note how the `write()` of 1024 bytes fails with `EINVAL`. `fwrite` iS note prepared to handle such errors: _"If an error occurs, the resulting value of the file-position indicator for the stream is unspecified_". You can, or should, use `ferror()` to check what happened.